# Degree of Field Extensions and $F(\alpha)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose that $[F(\alpha):F]$ is odd. Show that $F(\alpha)=F(\alpha^{2})$. Generalize this statement if possible.

---

Clearly, we always have that $F(\alpha^{2}) \subset F(\alpha)$ by definition of the field generated by $F$ and $\alpha$ (assuming that we have a field extension $K/F$ where $\alpha \in K$). However, how can we show the other inclusion? If the degree is odd, then it follows that $\alpha$ will solve a polynomial of odd degree in $K[x]$ (for the coefficients in $F$). What would be a way to proceed from here? (and as well to generalize the statement?)

I was thinking of using the formula: $[F(\alpha):F]=[F(\alpha):F(\alpha^{2})][F(\alpha^{2}):F]$ and maybe proceed from there.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial $X^2-\alpha^2\in F(\alpha^2)[X]$, so $[F(\alpha):F(\alpha^2)] \mid 2$.

Comment: Very simple and elegant, is it possible to generalize this statement in some way? Thanks!

Comment: A similar argument would show that $ F(\alpha) = F(\alpha^n)$ if $[F(\alpha):F]$ is coprime to $n$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I tried to prove that and couldn't figure out how. In particular, I got stuck on showing that the polynomial $x^n - a^n$ is irreducible in $F(a^n)$. Could you elaborate on how to obtain that result?

Comment: @MathUser_NotPrime What I wrote 2 years ago was incorrect. Thanks for pointing this out! For example, $[\mathbb Q(\zeta_5):\mathbb Q] = 4$, but certainly $\mathbb Q(\zeta_5^5)\ne \mathbb Q(\zeta_5)$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Thank you :-)