# Prove that $[F(u):F(u^{n})] \leq n$ for any positive integer $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $G$ be an extension of a field $F$ and let $u \in G$. I need to prove that $[F(u):F(u^{n})]\leq n$ for any positive integer $n$.

When I see "for any positive integer $n$", my mind says right away "Induction". Is that the correct intuition to have here?

In any case, this is the approach I took.

For the case where $n = 1$, we have the obvious statement that $[F(u):F(u)] = 1$, so that holds.

Now, for the $n =2$ case, I found some help in the answer given in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686112/degree-of-field-extensions-and-f-alpha) where it says that $[F(u):F(u^{2})] | 2$, since $u$ is a root of the polynomial $x^{2}-u^{2} \in F(u^{2})[x]$. If this is true, it certainly solves my dilemma for the $n=2$ case.

In fact, this answer says it can be generalized for any $n$, but I have a serious issue here: I don't see hows $u^{2}$ being a root of that polynomial tells me that the size of my basis for $F(u)$ over $F(u^{2})$ is divisible by 2. Could somebody please explain it to me, and also how to generalize it properly to all $n$: Do I use induction? And if so, how would the inductive step, $[F(u):F(u^{k})]|k$ help me establish that $[F(u):F(u^{k+1})]|(k+1)$?

Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: You don't need induction. Can't you use $x^n-u^n$, $\textit{similarly}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The degree of $F(u)$ over $F(u^n)$ is the same as the degree of the minimal polynomial for $u$ over $F(u^n)$.

Let $f(X)$ be this minimal polynomial. If $g(X)=X^n-u^n\in F(u^n)[X]$ then $g(u)=0$, and so $f$ divides $g$. This implies that $\deg(f)\leq \deg(g)=n$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $K=F(u^{n})$ and let $a = u^n \in K$.

Then $u$ is a root of $X^n-a \in K[X]$.

Therefore, $[K(u):K] \le n$.

Now, $K(u)=F(u,u^n)=F(u)$.

Therefore, $[F(u):F(u^n)]=[K(u):K] \le n$.

Comment: we haven't looked at extensions that aren't simple yet, so the substitutions aren't going to help.